# Retrive data from local json-server in VUE

Tags: json, vue.js, get, xmlhttprequest, sockjs

I am trying to fetch some data from a local server in a project done with VUE JS. The problem is that I receive a XHR response and I don't know why.
Here is the code:

```
async fetchTasks() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/tasks");
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
},
async created() {
  this.tasks = await this.fetchTasks();
}
```

And here is the response:  `XHR finished loading: GET "http://myIP:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1630002471497".`
Could you please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Notice that in your fetchTasks function you're querying http://localhost:5000, but the log message says "yourIP:8080" - so the ports are different. The message you're getting has nothing to do with fetchTasks - it's related to the hot-reloading of the app when you press CTRL+S

Comment: @walnut_salami, could you please give me more detailes. I am quite fresh in this domain and I am following a tutorial on youtube about VUE JS. And to practice HTTP methods, I did a local json server, which is running on port 5000, and the app  is running on port 8080. I've opened different terminals for each. `{"websocket":true,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":false,"entropy":2248581941}` -this is from Network>Fetch/XHR>Response

Comment: @walnut_salami The JSON server needs a different port than the app. The response in fact belongs to the XMLHttpRequests of the JSON server.